# how to show form in mdiparent from button in another form by C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two form ( **form1** and **form2** ) and **mdiparent** .
button1 in **form1** 
when click this button I want show **form2** in **mdiparent**

Comment: Look here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.mdiparent(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key points when you want to show a form in an MDI Parent, are:

- You should have an form with property `IsMdiContainer` set to `true`
- You should show your mdi parent form
- When you want to show a form as mdi child, Set the propetry `MdiParent` of your child form to and instance of your mdi parent form

So if your Form1 is showing as mdi Child, in button click handler of your form 1, you can simply do this:

```
var f = new Form2();
f.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
f.Show();
```

else, if your mdi parent form is open but form 1 is not mdi child:

```
var f = new Form2();
//I supposed that [mdiparent] is class name of your mdi parent form
f.MdiParent = Application.OpenForms.OfType<mdiparent>().FirstOrDefault();
f.Show();
```

esle you should show your mdi parent form first and use above code to show form 2 as mdi child.

Comment: Is Form1 mdichild? Is Your mdiParent is open?

Comment: form1 opened in mdiparent , I want show form2 in mdiparent when click button and close form1

Comment: @hadrmi I think the answer is correct and both options will work and the only thing you need is closing form1 using this.Close();

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need is to create a `Form2`, set it's `MdiParent` property and show it. The only problem is dynamically setting `MdiParent` property - you will need to hold the instance of `MdiParent`. There are several ways to do this "properly".

### Simple way

In `Form1` button click should have the following event handler:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 form = new Form2();
    form.MdiParent = this.MdiParent; // "this" is Form1
    form.Show();
}
```

This solution is less architectural - however, you can choose this one if it is suitable.

### Singleton solution

If I did this, I would use singleton pattern. That's how I would do this:

**`MdiParent`:**

```
public class MdiParent : Form
{
    private static MdiParent _instance; 
    public static MdiParent Instance
    {
        get { return _instance ?? (_instance = new MdiParent()); }
    }
}
```

**In the place where you instantiate your `MdiParent`**:

```
MdiParent.Instance.Show();
// instead of
new MdiParent().Show();
```

If it is a main form - `Main` in `Program.cs`:

```
Application.Run(MdiParent.Instance);
// instead of
Application.Run(new MdiParent());
```

**`Form1` button click event:**

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Form2 form = new Form2();
    form.MdiParent = MdiParent.Instance;        
    form2.Show();
}
```